# Detect when a user chooses a file using a file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-input

How can I detect when a user has chosen which file to upload using a html file input. That way I can submit the form automatically.

Answer (score 16):

The file upload element fires an onchange event when its contents have changed. Here's a very terse example:

```
<input type="file" name="whatever" onchange="alert('Changed!');" />
```

**EDIT:** Oh, and if you'd like to submit the form when they select something (although this will probably be a little confusing to your users):

```
<input type="file" name="whatever" onchange="this.form.submit();" />
```

Comment: Just noticed that you're using jQuery, in which case you'll want to use the change() event like Reigel suggested.

Answer (score 11):

A vanilla JavaScript way to detect a change in the file input:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('inputfileID')
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
  // Called when files change. You can for example:
  // - Access the selected files
  var singleFile = fileInput.files[0]
  // - Submit the form
  var formEl = document.getElementById('formID')
  formEl.submit()
}, false);
```

Just to mention: the attribute `false` means to not use capture i.e. `false` means that relevant `change` listeners in the DOM tree are executed in bottom-up order. It is the default value but you should always give the attribute to maximise compatibility.

See also [a SO answer about change event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31351612/638546), [MDN docs for addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), and [a SO answer about form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855663/638546).

Answer (score 9):

try

​

```
$('#inputfileID').change(function(){
alert(0);
})​
```