# How can I submit a form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a form with id `theForm` which has the following div with a submit button inside:

```html
<div id="placeOrder"
     style="text-align: right; width: 100%; background-color: white;">
    <button type="submit"
            class='input_submit'
            style="margin-right: 15px;"
            onClick="placeOrder()">Place Order
    </button>
</div>
```

When clicked, the function `placeOrder()` is called. The function changes the innerHTML of the above div to be "processing ..." (so the submit button is now gone).

The above code works, but now the problem is that I can't get the form to submit! I've tried putting this in the `placeOrder()` function:

```js
document.theForm.submit();
```

But that doesn't work.

How can I get the form to submit?

Comment: I take it you have a `<form>` tag someplace on your page.

Comment: I don't see any <form> in the code.

Comment: what do you mean by : The function changes the innerHTML of the above div to be "processing ..." (so the submit button is now gone).  and would you mind to share that logic . By the way if you have an submit button (somewhere down with name=submit ) , the theform.submit() function will not work . Please clarify you question by adding <form> tag as you have in your code . You might use http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: ...if you have an submit button (somewhere down with name=submit )... This solved my problem! It was <input type="button" name="submit" ..., but still blocking the javascript from sending the form.

Comment: `document.theForm.submit();` doesn't work, you'd rather need to use `document.getElementById("theForm").submit();` and specify the form id in HTML, for example: `<form id="theForm">(content)</form>`

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Set the `name` attribute of your form to `"theForm"` and your code will work.

Comment: This may seem super-obvious to some, but i had a button with the name and id "submit", and `document.theForm.submit()` reported an error.  Once I renamed my button, the code worked perfectly.

Comment: @Jonathan What is the name of button you had? Coz, as per https://api.jquery.com/submit/ child elements of a form should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form.

Answer (score 182):

You can use...

```
document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
```

...but **don't** replace the `innerHTML`. You could hide the form and then insert a *processing...* `span` which will *appear* in its place.

```
var form = document.getElementById('theForm');

form.style.display = 'none';

var processing = document.createElement('span');

processing.appendChild(document.createTextNode('processing ...'));

form.parentNode.insertBefore(processing, form);
```

Comment: How do you tell it where to send the form? For example, in my case, I want the content emailed to me

Comment: @Imray You'll probably want server-side code to do that for you.

Comment: @CodyBugstein set `action="/{controller}/{action-method}" method="post"` attributes of the form you are trying to post.

Comment: as my form name is printoffersForm as well as id is same. `document.getElementById('printoffersForm').submit();` but i gives me error submit is not an function

Comment: @MadhuriPatel Could be you have your submit button also named submit? See answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript

Answer (score 56):

It works perfectly in my case.

```
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
```

Also, you can use it in a function as below:

```
function formSubmit()
{
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
}
```

Comment: will this submit form values from an `input` tag?

Comment: @roy Yes, it will submit form values from input tags.

Comment: @ChintanThummar and then you can handle the [Form submit](http://mycodingtricks.com/javascript/submit-form-using-javascript-ajax/) using 

    document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = function(){

      //You can use Ajax Code here to submit the form
      // without refreshing page
    
    }

Answer (score 26):

```
document.forms["name of your form"].submit();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("form id").submit();
```

You can try any of this...this will definitely work...

Comment: In order to get the first one to work I had to change it to document.forms.namedItem("FormName").submit();

Answer (score 14):

I will leave the way I do to submit the form without using the `name` tag inside the form:

#### HTML

```
<button type="submit" onClick="placeOrder(this.form)">Place Order</button>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function placeOrder(form){
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding `type="button"` in the HTML part. Otherwise the button will e.g. submit in a form.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the below code to submit the form using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('FormID').submit();
```

Answer (score 14):

```html
<html>

    <body>

        <p>Enter some text in the fields below, and then press the "Submit form" button to submit the form.</p>

        <form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
          First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
          Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
          <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">
        </form>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer might be helpful for some https://stackoverflow.com/a/54619085/7003760

Answer (score 6):

### HTML

```
<!-- change id attribute to name  -->

<form method="post" action="yourUrl" name="theForm">
    <button onclick="placeOrder()">Place Order</button>
</form>
```

### JavaScript

```
function placeOrder () {
    document.theForm.submit()
}
```

Comment: This does not improve the quality of the answers that are already given.

Comment: It's the only answer that shows the form name in the actual html for the form definition.  Also, it's simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

If your form does not have any id, but it has a class name like theForm, you can use the below statement to submit it:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("theForm")[0].submit();
```

Comment: what about there are more forms with the same class name above?

Answer (score 1):

I have came up with an easy resolve using a simple form hidden on my website with the same information the users logged in with. Example: If you want a user to be logged in on this form, you can add something like this to the follow form below.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="autologin" id="autologin" />
```

As far I know I am the first to hide a form and submit it via clicking a link. There is the link submitting a hidden form with the information. It is not 100% safe if you don't like auto login methods on your website with passwords sitting on a hidden form password text area...

Okay, so here is the work. Let’s say `$siteid` is the account and `$sitepw` is password.

First make the form in your PHP script. If you don’t like HTML in it, use minimal data and then `echo` in the value in a hidden form. I just use a PHP value and echo in anywhere I want pref next to the form button as you can't see it.

#### PHP form to print

```
$hidden_forum = '
<form id="alt_forum_login" action="./forum/ucp.php?mode=login" method="post" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="'.strtolower($siteid).'" title="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="'.$sitepw.'" title="Password" />
</form>';
```

#### PHP and link to submit form

```
<?php print $hidden_forum; ?>
<pre><a href="#forum" onClick="javascript: document.getElementById('alt_forum_login').submit();">Forum</a></pre>
```

Comment: True you need to submit form but the link wont appear in my coding sorry but make a onclick or href=javascript:   document.getElementById('alt_forum_login').submit()

Comment: The question is about javascript, there's no need for the php code at all

Comment: 1. I have to strongly discourage anybody from using something like this: Sending your passwords in clear text to the browser is a HUGE security flaw.
2. This response doesn't relate to the question

Your effort to provide help is appreciated! But please be more careful around security topics. It's tempting for many to copy solutions from stackoverflow without fully understanding them.

Answer (score 0):

```
let form = document.getElementById('theForm');
let div = document.getElementById('placeOrder');
let span = document.createElement('span');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    div.style.display = 'none';
    span.innerText = 'processing...';
    form.appendChild(span);

    console.log('form is submitted.');
})
```

> This is how you should approach this issue
> This answer is for new developers who kind of face this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I know this is very old question but this might help some new developers There are multiple ways to get this form working but here is a simple tweak
> Here is the code

```
<form action="/" class="form" id="theForm">
            <div id="placeOrder"
                style="text-align: right; width: 100%; background-color: white;">
                <button type="submit"
                        class='input_submit'
                        style="margin-right: 15px;"
                        onclick="placeOrder()">Place Order
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>

<script>
function placeOrder(){ 
            let form = document.getElementById('theForm');
            let div = document.getElementById('placeOrder');
            let span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerText = 'Processing...';
            document.querySelector('button.input_submit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            div.appendChild(span);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you land here looking for the best way to submit a form using a button outside the form:

As of HTML5, just use the button's `form` attribute.

```
<button type="submit" form="my_form_id">Submit</button>
```

This method can submit forms in unique contexts (eg: Stripe's iframe based PaymentElement) that JS inline onClicks won't work with.

[Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)