# Html.BeginForm with html attributes asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Edit Action with `Html.BeginForm`. How can I add HTML attributes?

I know only one way:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Clients", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="example"})) {

}
```

but if I use this method I cannot pass current ID

Is it possible to add HTML attributes to form without modifying action URL?

Comment: Are you using strongly typed view

Comment: Yes...........................

Comment: What is the current id and why can't you pass it?

Comment: And what HTTP method do you want to use? You can easily specify `FormMethod.Get` or whatever instead of `FormMethod.Post` here if you want to.

Comment: Than why is it a problem to just get id from the model you pass

Comment: Why not put a ',' and add a id attribute. You can append multiple atrributes like that. `@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Clients", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="example", id = Model.Id}))`    Is this you are looking for or what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The override you need is:

```
@using( Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Clients", new { Id=Model.Id},
                       FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "example" } ) )
{
}
```

- Route values like "id" are passed as the third parameter.
- HTML attributes like "class" are passed as the fifth parameter.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) docs.

Comment: And of course you can also pass `@id="blah"` in the 5th parameter object, which will have the completely different effect of setting the HTML id of the rendered form tag.

Comment: First two parameters can be null if you want to post to same action (Post method) of current controller like:

`@using(Html.BeginForm(null, null, new {Id=Model.Id}, FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "example"}))`

Answer (score 21):

The Action and Controller parameters can also be null to use the default action:

```
Html.BeginForm( null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id=”formname”, @class="formclass" })
```

Comment: Indeed it does.

Answer (score 2):

Calling via an ActionLink from ControllerA

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create",
    "StudentPChoice",
    new { StudentPChoiceId = Model.StudentPChoiceId },
    FormMethod.Post))
{

}
```

OR

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create",
    "ControllerB",
    new { ControllerBId = Model.ControllerAId },
    FormMethod.Post))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this might be helpful for some people, this works for me:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RefreshData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
        new { Id = "timerangeId", @name = "timerange" }))
    {
        // form elements and input
    }
```

In Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("timerangeId").submit();
```