# Enable checkbox and press edit button and open in a popup

Tags: php, mysql

I am showing records in a table from the MySQL database, each record/row has a checkbox, now I have a button to change, but I want to first select the checkbox of any record and send me a popup, in this popup has to registry data show checkbox selected for editing.

From already thank you very much.

```
while ($rsEmp = mysql_fetch_assoc($queEmp)) { .....



echo "<tr>
<td bgcolor='#E6E6E6' class=item_listado_registros align=center><input name=casilla[] type=checkbox id=checkbox[] value=$rsEmp[id]></td>
<td id=linkreg href=# id=linkregistro onclick=Abrir_ventana('popup_ver_compra.php?id=$rsEmp[id]') align=center bgcolor='#E6E6E6' class=item_listado_registros align=center>".$rsEmp['codigo']."</a></td>
<td id=linkreg href=# id=linkregistro onclick=Abrir_ventana('popup_ver_compra.php?id=$rsEmp[id]') align=center bgcolor='#E6E6E6' class=item_listado_registros align=center>".$rsEmp['cantidad']."</td>
echo "<tr>

<button class="boton_data"  onclick="Valida_mod(); Abrir_ventana('new_popup.php?id=$rsEmp[id]')" id="btn_agregar">Modificar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isset` to check which checkboxes were selected.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitbutton'])){//check if submit button clicked
  if(isset($_POST['checkboxes'])){ // check if checkbox checked
      //get checkbox details and display
      $checked = $_POST['checkboxes'];
      for($i=0;$i<count($checked);$i++){
          echo $checked[$i]."<br/>";
      }
  }else{
      //display error message
  }

}

echo '<form name="" action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'" method="POST">

</form>';
   //table with checkbox
   //button
?>
```

This is just a quick way and I am sure there are lot of other ways tackle this.

Comment: Great, if I send the record to the popup.
But do not select the checkbox.
I want you to show me the log data checkbox labeled.

For example I have a list of 10 records, and if the checkbox active record 6.
I want to show only that record chekckbox marked with a popup.

Comment: @JuanCastroLurita I have edited the code above, i hope that is what you were asking for. Can you please explain your requirements in detail.

Comment: my button is out of form. I want to send the values ​​to a popup

Comment: use javascript `document.form.submit();`

Comment: you have a example, please brother.

Comment: the example in the link [HTML DOM Form submit() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp), [How to Submit a Form Using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript). and there are many more examples if you google.

Comment: Achieve fix, but I have other problems that are not of this topic.
Thanks for your help has helped me a lot. I hope I can help at some time.