# How to upload a customize <input type=“file”> without submit button

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to upload an img and store it in DB without a submit button?

**CSS**

```
#upload-file-container {
   width: 90px;
   height: 90px;
   position: relative;
   border:2px solid;
   border-radius:20px;
   border-color:rgb(58,147,231);
   color:rgb(58,147,231);
   overflow: hidden;
   float:right;
}

#upload-file-container input[type="file"] {
   margin: 0;
   opacity: 0;   
   font-size: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="upload-file-container" >
   <input type="file"  value="No Picture"/>
</div>
```

or do you have to put a submit button to be able to store it ? I wonder ؟_؟

Comment: How are you initiating the upload without a submit button?

Comment: so how Facebook upload the image directly when the user choose it ??

Comment: Where are you uploading to? You won't be able to upload anything without a form which initiates the request for the upload to a destination.

Comment: i think you cand to this but with hiding the submit button and trigger it with javascript when the file input is set:-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jquery upload, dropzone.](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Drop-zone-effects)

or

[DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) is an open source library that provides drag'n'drop file uploads with image previews.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. It requires a form and a form submits info using submit button or you can use JavaScript. Something like this `document.getElementById('theForm').submit();`

Source: [How to submit a form using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript)

Comment: yes I will use JavaScript to submit it thank you for the help