# How to submit form based on certain condition?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have one form data.php with following form structure.

```
 <div id="form-container" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">

  var x=Math.random();;
  if(x > 0.5)
  {
      submit form
  } 


 <p style="width: 100%; text-align: right;"><button type="button" id="submit-button">Sumit</button></p>
```

How form can be automatically submitted based on x value? Which means button should be pressed automatically.

Comment: You need to use javascript (or jquery). Take a look [here:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript)

Comment: You mean that right when someone enters any value (Or a specific value) into X it should submit the form?

Comment: @MorHaviv yes it should be automatically submitted when some enter x value.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById('theForm').submit();

Comment: Will this submit form without pressing button?

Comment: But in my case button is having Jquery action so it must be pressed.

Comment: so your question is not quite asked well i propose. 
Correct me if i am wrong please: 
if(x > 0.5) and you pressed the button => Form should be submitted.
if(x < 0.5) and you pressed the button => form shouldn't be submitted ?

Comment: No if x> 0.5 only then button should be pressed and submitted.

Comment: if x >0.5, the button should be pressed automatically or by a user ??

Comment: You can add an asp.net value validation, the button will not be submitted unless the value is valid and > 0.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69599/discussion-between-user15662-and-nada-naeem).

Comment: add a java script on value change on that x value, and check, if the value of x > 0.5 then do the document.getElementById('theForm').submit();

Comment: Should be pressed automatically...
there must be two options one user can submit
and other based on event for generating number
if event generates x>0.5 it will press the button and call Jquery for fetching data through ajax

Comment: But i do not have have structure (only div id) so document.getElementById('theForm').submit(); cannnot be used.

Comment: check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1

Comment: why can't you simply add a form and place your div inside it?

Comment: Actually div element is already present in one form so i cannot use another form. So easiest way to fetch data using ajax.

Comment: please comment out with your solution.