# No action when submitting form using getElementbyID()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am C++ Programmer and new to JS World.

This refers to my previous question.

[How to submit form based on certain condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137277/how-to-submit-form-based-on-certain-condition)

I am trying to submit my form using document.getElementById based on certain condition but there is no output.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<title>jQuery.post demo</title>
<body>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div id="form-container" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">

<script>
  var x=Math.random();;
  if(x > 0.5)
  {
      //document.writeln(x);
      document.getElementById('form-container').submit();
  }  
</script>
X Value: <input type="text" name="X"><br>
<br>
<p style="text-align: left;"><button type="button" id="submit-button">Submit</button></p>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#submit-button').click(function(event){
    $('#form-container').submit();
  )};
)};
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a form element in your code.

Comment: the answer is one of your tags, you need `<form>`

Answer (score 3):

You can't do a .submit() on a `<div>`! You need a `<form>` Tag with an `Action` and an `method` Attribute.

The `action` Atrribute tells the browser where he has  to send the data and the `method` Attribute says on what way (POST or GET) to send the Data.

```
<form Action="process.php" method="POST">
```

Of course you can add an `ID` too, for the identification of the form.

Comment: But i have one code  part of my project where i have div element on the page which has submit button on clicking submitting button it generates some plots using data filled in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a form in your HTML and specify properties to allow form submission:

```
<form id="form-container" action="url to your action where the form submit request will hit" method="get">
```

Ref : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_form_tag.htm

Comment: In my case there is no action but Jquery is attached with button which generates plot.

Comment: One example is like button call Jquery function                                $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });

Answer (score 0):

you should submit form not div
so include url and method type in form tag