# I made an HTML form and I want to use a link to submit it

Tags: html, forms, button

I made an HTML form to add a friend on my website and I want to be able to submit it with a link I made. I have tried to do `onClick="form.submit();"` but that didn't work.

[PIC OF WEBSITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jApd.png)

```
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="Forum-Block">
        <div class="Top-Bar">
            <a href="http://site/Forum.php"><div class="Back-Box">Back</div></a>
            <a href="http://site/ShowFriends.php"><div class="FriendsB-Box">Friends</div></a>
            <a href="http://site/ShowSentRequests.php"><div class="RequestsB-Box">Sent Requests</div></a>
            <a href="http://site/AddFriend.php"><div class="SendRequestB-Box">Send Request</div></a>
        </div>
        <div class="FriendRequestSend-Box">
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" name="friendname"/>
                <br/>
                <a href="http://site/AddFriendPHP.php" onclick="form.submit();"><div class="FriendRequestSend-Button">Send</div></a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why didn't it work, what error do you get, have you tried anything else. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `form` isn't defined as a javascript variable anywhere. You can give your `<form>` tag a name like "myFormName", then get it from the DOM using `document.myFormName`. Once you have the DOM element for the form, *then* you can call `submit()` on it.

I should also mention that it's generally considered bad practice to put javascript inline in tags. You can do it, but it's not ideal. Instead, you should add it in a `<script>` tag or separate .js file.

```
<head>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('mySubmitLink').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
...
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="friendname"/>
    <br/>
    <a href="http://site/AddFriendPHP.php" id="mySubmitLink"><div class="FriendRequestSend-Button">Send</div></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [How to submit a form using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript)

So basically give you form a name like this:

```
<form method="post" name="theForm">...</form>
```

and do something like this for the javascript:

```
document.theFormName.submit();
```

(So the link would be something like:

```
<a href="http://site/AddFriendPHP.php" onclick="document.theFormName.submit();"><div class="FriendRequestSend-Button">Send</div></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: i was wondering if anyone knew how to do it with a link instead of that

Comment: What is the purpose of having it inside an anchor tag? What are you trying to accomplish?