# Form Validation won't work using javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've been testing my code all day, but nothing happens. The form automatically opens the success.html and doesn't use the script.

```js
 function FormValidation(theForm) {
     var errors = "";
     var alph = /^[\w ]+$/;
     var cardnumb = /^\d{16}$/;
     var cvvnumb = /^\d{3}$/;
     var monthnumb = /^\d{1,2}$/;
     var yearnumb = /^\d{4}$/;

     if (form.one.value == "") {
         errors += "Please enter your full name! \n";
  }

     else if (!alph.test(form.one.value)) {
         errors += "Full name is wrong or includes invalid characters! \n";
     }
     if (form.two.value == "") {
         errors += "Please enter your 16-digit code! \n";
     }

     if (!cardnumb.test(form.two.value)) {
         errors += "Card number does not consist of 16 digits or includes invalid characters! \n";
     }

     if (form.three.value == "") {
         errors += "Please enter your month of expiration! \n";
     }

     if (!monthnumb.test(form.three.value)) {
         errors += "The month does not consist of 2 digits or includes invalid characters! \n";
     }
      
     if (form.four.value == "") {
         errors += "Please enter your year of expiration! \n";
     }

     if (!yearnumb.test(form.four.value)) {
         errors += "The year does not consist of 4 digits or includes invalid characters! \n";
     }

     if (form.five.value == "") {
         errors += "Please enter your 3-digit CVV code! \n";
     }

     if (!cvvnumb.test(form.five.value)) {
         errors += "The CVV does not consist of 3 digits or includes invalid characters! \n";
     }
      
     if (!content == "") {
      alert(content);
      return false;
  }
 }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US" class="Html" id="Main" dir="auto">
    <head class="Head" id="Main">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta name="description" content="NRN">
 <meta name="author" content="NRN">
 <title class="Title" id="Title">NRN</title>

   
    </head>
    <body class="Body" id="Main">
 <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
 <p class="p1">Payment form validation using JavaScript<p>
 <form method="POST" action="success.html" class="myForm" name="myForm" onSubmit="javascript:return FormValidation(this)">
 <div class="form-group-name">
        <label for="name">Owner</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name on card" class="form-control-1" id="one" name="one">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-number">
        <label for="number">Card number</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="16-digit code" class="form-control-2" id="two" name="two">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-date">
        <label for="date">Expiration date</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Month" class="form-control-3" id="three" name="three">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Year" class="form-control-3" id="four" name="four">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-cvv">
        <label for="cvv">CVV</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="3-digit code" class="form-control-4" id="five" name="five">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-submit">
        <input type="submit" class="submit_form" value="Validate">
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have checked everything, as well as many tutorials too, but it doesn't help. Please help! Thanks in advance! Could the problem be in the .css file?

Comment: When i hit submit i see in console this error: 
Blocked form submission to 'success.html' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

Comment: Second error in console:Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript validation function is never returning false, because `content` is never equal to `""`, `content` is nowhere set so it will be undefined, so the form keeps submitting even if an error occurred.

For a start you should change

```
if (!content == "") {
    alert(content);
    return false;
}
```

To

```
if (!errors == "") {
    alert(errors);
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

If your javascript function returns `true`, the form will continue submitting. If it returns `false`, in case of an error, it will stop submitting the form.

In addition you can set a function in the `onSubmit` attribute on the `form` element like this:

```
<form onSubmit="return FormValidation(this)""></form>
```

as mentioned by Tulio Faria

Answer (score 0):

in fact onSubmit already expect a Javascript function. So, you can do this instead (remove the javascript: from onSubmit):

`<form method="POST" action="success.html" class="myForm" name="myForm" onSubmit="return FormValidation(this)">`

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'form' with 'theFrom' in you function

you can debug and find that form is undefined here

```
if (form.one.value == "") {
    errors += "Please enter your full name! \n";
}
```

replace it with 'theForm' every where in function FormValidation

```
if (theForm.one.value == "") {
    errors += "Please enter your full name! \n";
}
```

again content is not defined here

```
 if (!content == "") {
     alert(content);
     return false;
 }
```

it should be error instead

```
if (!errors == "") {
    alert(errors);
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Here's your working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="Html" id="Main" dir="auto">
<head class="Head" id="Main">
<meta name="description" content="NRN">
<meta name="author" content="NRN">
<title class="Title" id="Title">NRN</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function FormValidation(theForm) {
    var errors = "";
    var alph = /^[\w ]+$/;
    var cardnumb = /^\d{16}$/;
    var cvvnumb = /^\d{3}$/;
    var monthnumb = /^\d{1,2}$/;
    var yearnumb = /^\d{4}$/;

    if (theForm.one.value == "") {
        errors += "Please enter your full name! \n";
    }

    else if (!alph.test(theForm.one.value)) {
        errors += "Full name is wrong or includes invalid characters! \n";
    }
    if (theForm.two.value == "") {
        errors += "Please enter your 16-digit code! \n";
    }

    if (!cardnumb.test(theForm.two.value)) {
        errors += "Card number does not consist of 16 digits or includes invalid characters! \n";
    }

    if (theForm.three.value == "") {
        errors += "Please enter your month of expiration! \n";
    }

    if (!monthnumb.test(theForm.three.value)) {
        errors += "The month does not consist of 2 digits or includes invalid characters! \n";
    }

    if (theForm.four.value == "") {
        errors += "Please enter your year of expiration! \n";
    }

    if (!yearnumb.test(theForm.four.value)) {
        errors += "The year does not consist of 4 digits or includes invalid characters! \n";
    }

    if (theForm.five.value == "") {
        errors += "Please enter your 3-digit CVV code! \n";
    }

    if (!cvvnumb.test(theForm.five.value)) {
        errors += "The CVV does not consist of 3 digits or includes invalid characters! \n";
    }

    if (!errors == "") {
        alert(errors);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body class="Body" id="Main">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p class="p1">Payment form validation using JavaScript<p>
<form method="POST" action="success.html" class="myForm" name="myForm" onSubmit="javascript:return FormValidation(this)">
<div class="form-group-name">
    <label for="name">Owner</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name on card" class="form-control-1" id="one" name="one">
</div>
<div class="form-group-number">
    <label for="number">Card number</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="16-digit code" class="form-control-2" id="two" name="two">
</div>
<div class="form-group-date">
    <label for="date">Expiration date</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Month" class="form-control-3" id="three" name="three">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Year" class="form-control-3" id="four" name="four">
</div>
<div class="form-group-cvv">
    <label for="cvv">CVV</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="3-digit code" class="form-control-4" id="five" name="five">
</div>
<div class="form-group-submit">
    <input type="submit" class="submit_form" value="Validate">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need to handle the  submit event, so your function needs an additional parameter (event) and the first code line inside of it (the function) must be event.preventDefault() so when you submit the form before submit it your function will be executed, and then at the end of your code if the validation went ok submit your form using js as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript). You'll have something like

```
function formValidation(theForm, event)
{
    event.preventDefault()
    //your code

    if(allOk)
   {           theForm.submit()
}
    else
{
   //do something
}


}
```

On the HTML side you'll have

```
<form method="POST" action="success.html" class="myForm" name="myForm" onSubmit="return FormValidation(this, event)">
```