# How to submit form after JavaScript validation

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate my form using javascript before submitting it. I validated all fields successfully but my form is not getting submitted.

Comment: here is my code

Comment: <form class="login-form"  method="post" name='registration' onSubmit="return formValidation();">

Comment: Please provide more details such as the HTML and javascript files

Comment: Do you return "true" in the function "formValidation()"?

Comment: Please add your code in your answer itself instead of in comments.

Comment: Please go read [ask], and provide all relevant code in the question.

Comment: <script>
      function formValidation()  
    {  
 var ufullname = document.registration.fullname;
 
 var uemail = document.registration.email;

Comment: You should use the edit-button to add code into the question instead of adding it as comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit a form using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

**Pure Javascript**

you can use the HTML DOM `submit()` function:

`document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`

Read more about the function here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

**With Jquery**

`$("#myForm").submit(/* Callback */);`

Read more about the jquery function in the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/submit/