# Html and angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I have some fields inside a form tag and submit button outside a form tag. If any of the fields inside a form is empty my form should not be submitted. For this I used the `required` attribute but it was not working since submit button was outside of the `<form>` and also used `novalidate` attribute. Nothing seems to work.

Below is my code:

```
<section id="profile" class="content-header">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" ng-if="!viewProfile" ng-click="updateProfile();">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <form name="profileForm" role="form">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="firstName"> First Name </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" ng- model="profileDetails.firstName" ng-disabled="viewProfile" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-if="userDetails.role==0">
        <label for="firstName"> Middle Name </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="middleName" ng- model="profileDetails.middleName" ng-disabled="viewProfile" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

like `FirstName` and `MiddleName` there are many other fields without filling any of those fields my form should not be submitted, can anyone suggest me the best approach for this. My angularController is:

```
(function() {
  function profileController($scope, profileFactory, $loading) {
    $scope.updateProfile = function() {
      $loading.start("main");
      profileFactory
        .updateProfile($scope.profileDetails)
        .then(function(response) {
          var updatedUserDetails = response.user;
          if (updatedUserDetails.imagePath !== null) {
            $scope.profileDetails.imagePath = updatedUserDetails.imagePath;
            $scope.profileDetails.profieImageBytes = updatedUserDetails.profieImageBytes;
          }
          angular.extend($scope.userDetails, $scope.profileDetails);
          $scope.editProfile();
        })
        .catch(function() {
          $loading.finish("main");
        });
    };
    $loading.finish("main");
  }
  profileController.$inject = ["$scope", "profileFactory", "$loading"];
  angular
    .module("vResume.profile")
    .controller("profileController", profileController);
})();
```

Comment: You can submit the form via JavaScript in your `updateProfile()` function.  See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript

Comment: please post your js also

Comment: In our application we were not using JavaScript,its totally based on Angular-mrogers

Comment: @vyas Angular is a framework/library built on JavaScript.  All the code you write in your controllers is JavaScript.

Comment: yaa i mean to say we are not using plain javaScript rather we are using AngularJS i posted my js snippet also-mrogers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically use the `.$invalid` field on the form with ng-disabled for this.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" ng-disabled="profileForm.$invalid" ng-if="!viewProfile" ng-click="updateProfile();">SUBMIT</button>
```

See the [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$invalid).

Comment: yaa already tried that,it was not working even if i doesnt give all the fields,form is being submitted

Comment: Then you have something else going on, because that is almost the main use for form.$invalid. Add a minimal plunkr, jsbin, jsfiddle, etc.

Comment: try just getting rid of type="submit" from the button.

Comment: yaa thanks for your contribution,it was working now i just made a mistake since i didnt worked now it was working fine,tahnk you -seth flowers