# HTML Form Post &/ Javascript form submit

Tags: javascript, html

It's been a while Im stumbling on this:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="description-logo">
    <form action="/memes.php" method="POST" id="suckers">
        <div class="card" id="kappas22">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="content text-center">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>16 Digits</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" name="digits" value="<?php echo $company ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="content text-center">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" disabled name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="content text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="content text-center">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Home Address" name="address" value="<?php echo $address ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="content text-center">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Country</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Country" name="country" value="<?php echo $country ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content text-center">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Zip Code</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="ZIP Code" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" onclick="keppas()" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right">Add</button>

        <script>
            function keppas() {
                document.getElementById('suckers').submit();
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

It might seems stupid but the same thing Im trying with the javascript I tried also with a button but it won't work in the same way...
Error in console when clicked the button is:

> Cannot read property 'submit' of null

I also tried with a submit button but it doesn't seem to want to work... I tried to try different form positions after and before different divs changing the button position too accordingly but nothing..

Edit: Trying it in JSFiddle seems to work, but in my code it won't. Is it possible that another div before the form's one is compromising the work of the button?

Comment: Your code seems to be working. Try in incognito. Might be that your old code is being cached

Comment: Already did so, again 20 seconds ago... Can another div before the form's one compromise the button's work?

Comment: can you give `console.log(document.forms)` before line `document.getElementById('suckers').submit();` and see whether you get any forms in console

Comment: Make sure not to have elements with same ids

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit a form using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript)

Comment: @AswinRamesh HTMLCollection(2) [form.navbar-form.navbar-left.navbar-search-form, form]
0
:
form.navbar-form.navbar-left.navbar-search-form
1
:
form
length
:
2
__proto__
:
HTMLCollection
item
:
ƒ item()
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
length
:
1
name
:
"item"
__proto__
:
ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[0]
length
:
(...)
namedItem
:
ƒ namedItem()
constructor
:
ƒ HTMLCollection()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator)
:
ƒ values()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
:
"HTMLCollection"
get length
:
ƒ ()
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: @JenniferMiller if so it doesn't have the form with id as `suckers` right?, that`s why your line `document.getElementById('suckers').submit();` is failing, can you also paste the render html(only this form section)

Comment: Your code looks okay, so there is likely something else going on (perhaps, as you mentioned, from another element on the page). Unless you actually need to submit the form using JavaScript, I'd try @MohammadWaleed's solution below (using an actual submit button) and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot adding `name` attribute to your `form`. 
  The `W3C` specification, if I understand it correctly, mandates that every form input element has a name attribute specified. Otherwise that element will not be processed.

```
 document.suckers.submit();
```

[Look at here .](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)

Comment: does the name have something to do in this case since it gets element by id and id is set?

Comment: @manikantgautam I don't think this is true. See the W3C spec here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-name-FORM. It states that `name` is added for backwards compatibility. Also, there should really be no difference between using `document.name.submit()` and `document.getElementById(id).submit()` as long as the `name` and `id` values are specified properly.

Answer (score 0):

in your use case do you really need javascript to submit the form ?
why didn't you use `type="submit"`

like this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right">Add</button>
```

this would work without any issues

---

If you have to use javascript remember that `getElementById` or any selector really works from top the document to bottom

So in your case there might be another html tag with the same id as the form you want to submit and it comes before your form, so the selector will return that html tag instead of the form

Comment: After some edits of closing unclosed html tags the javascript code worked to submit the post, but if I switch back to this case it won't do anything.