# Pressing enter key through console

Tags: javascript, browser

I was just fiddling around with [slack](https://slack.com/). The slackbot sends different replies for "Hi". So I just wished to find out the various types of replies that it gives(using the programmer's way ;) ). For that I wrote this code in the console of my browser

```
var ft = document.getElementById("msg_input").getElementsByClassName("ql-editor")[0].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
for(var i =0 ;i<10;i++)
{
    ft.innerHTML ="Hi";
    //some line of code that sends the above "Hi"

}
```

This code does the first part of what I want: "Hi" is inserted in the textbox(actually a paragraph). The second part is to send the message by pressing the enter key. And now I am stuck. I wish to press enter through the console and I have no idea of how to do this.

P.S. : The answer to the question here at [How to submit a form using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript) does explain how to submit a form by adding the name attribute to the form and then document..submit(). But in my case, the form had no name attribute so I added one to it and then ran document..submit() but it actually reloaded the window with this error in the console

> May-31 09:05:43.132 SOCKET-MANAGER (TAUM2F7AR) Closing socket because
>
> ## 4108: unexpected socket closure

I also tried the same with id of the form but even that didn't work.

The answer to the question [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically) also did not help.[This is the code that I ran(Note event keycode is 13)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM7tB.png) and this is the screenshot of the result [When I queried for the keycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpquz.png) (Note that it gives the keycode as 0). Moreover, I am using Firefox(and not Chrome) so I don't know why is it automatically gets changed to 0 even though I wrote 13.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit a form using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript)

Comment: The slack web app presumably uses AJAX or websockets, not form submission.

Comment: I have no idea about what it uses. But I definitely wish to know is it possible? Like is there a way out of it?