# Input field filled with value green correct sign appears but form not submitted

Tags: javascript

I want to submit form but form submit button does not work, 
Please Guide me. I want to submit my form using javascript. Form validation is working fine but I am unable to submit my form. I am new user. If any one help me to submit this form.

I have a code:

```js
});
```

```html
<link href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<div class="page-content">
  <div class="form-v4-content">
    <form class="form-detail" action="abc.html" method="post" id="myform">
      <h2>REGISTER FORM</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row form-row-1">
          <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input-text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row form-row-1">
          <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input-text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="your_email">Your Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="your_email" id="your_email" class="input-text" required pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row form-row-1 ">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row form-row-1">
          <label for="comfirm-password">Comfirm Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="comfirm_password" id="comfirm_password" class="input-text" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-checkbox">
        <label class="container"><p>I agree to the <a href="#" class="text">Terms and Conditions</a></p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row-last">
        <input type="submit" name="register" class="register" value="Register">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just want to submit my form. I don't know what is the problem

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I used this code in javascript tag

Comment: I want to submit a form with that validation

Comment: May I put complete html code here

Comment: I am a new user

Comment: as I put html code here it shows some error

Comment: as I edit my question it shows an error
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: I have put my all code, please check now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit a form using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript)

Comment: its not a duplicate

Comment: please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

The form doesn't submit because you told it not to.

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
```

From the [docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#debug):

> debug (default: false)
>   Type: Boolean
>   Enables debug mode. If true, the form is not submitted...