# How to submit form in Vue 3 only when function is called

Tags: laravel, forms, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Does anyone know how I can submit a sign out form in Vue 3 only when a function is called?
I have inserted related code below:

```html
<form
@submit.prevent="handleSignOut($event)"
method="post"
action="/logout">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
<button type="submit">
Sign out
</button>
</form>
```

```
// handle sign out
const handleSignOut = function (e) {
// submit sign out here
}
```

Comment: Yes. Do `e.currentTarget.submit()`: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I submit a form using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-can-i-submit-a-form-using-javascript)

Comment: You need to change `@submit.prevent` to `@submit` because the `prevent` modifier will call `preventDefault` that prevents the form from submitting

Answer (score 2):

if you're using javascript:

1. add a tag ref on your html form `<form ref="myForm" @submit.prevent="handleSignOut($event)" method="post" action="/logout">`
2. `this.$refs.myForm.submit()`

if you'e using typescript:

1. add a tag ref on your html form `<form ref="myForm" @submit.prevent="handleSignOut($event)" method="post" action="/logout">`
2. you need to declare `const myForm = ref<HTMLFormElement>()`
3. `myForm.value.submit();`