# Dom Event TextArea Change without Jquery

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm creating a project and for it to be faster, I have chosen not to use jQuery(I would use only 5% of the full potential of the library).

In this project, I have a `<textarea>` element, and need to get the contents every time it changes. I have tried different examples, but none worked.

How do I write the following code using Vanilla JavaScript and native DOM Events?

```
$("#textarea").bind('input propertychange')
// or
$("#textarea").bind('change')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) is an alias for native [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event.

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`
>   elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the
>   user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily
>   fired for each change to an element's value.

You can use it fairly simple:

```
// Non-obtrusive JavaScript example(preffered).    
element.addEventListener('change', callback, false);

// Somewhat obtrusive (not recommended).
element.onchange = function () { ... };

// Obtrusive JavaScript in HTML (not recommended).
<input type="text" onchange="function() { ... };">
```

Answer (score -4):

Here's the plain vanilla js way to change content in the DOM.

```
document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = put your new HTML here
```

Also you probably want to pick a better id than `textarea` as that's awfully generic.